# How to choose different colors from ColorPicker and apply it to a text or different shapes in the same screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, touchscreen, color-picker

[image]

If user selects any color from colorpicker then should be able to apply it to a text or different shapes in a same activity or screen in Android.

In my screen, shapes and color picker is there. By using onTouch event, I could be able to draw different shapes . Also I can write anything on  a screen. In my app, color picker works fine.

At first- if I draw triangle and write some text like "meena", then applied blue color from color picker, it works fine

At second- In the same screen (below the text "meena") I clicked rose color from color picker and chose different shapes like rectangle and I wrote a word apple. I have already opted for rose color this time.

So from first and second step, the whole different shapes and words are applied in a rose color .

My question is, how can user choose a different colors from color picker and can write a text or draw different shapes in different color in the touch screen using touch event in a same activity or screen? So, in the entire screen different colors could be find.

But, my problem is, in the entire screen only one color has applied.

I want to apply colors from the color picker to the text in the same screen or activity like this. See above image for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need you use paint and change the paint color as picked by color picker and invalidate the code like this

```
public class DrawPaint extends View{
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
Paint circlePaint = new Paint();

public DrawPaint(Context context){
    super(context);
    //set default colors for them 
    textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawText("mu text " , 0 , 0 , textPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(10 , 10 , 20 , circlePaint);
}

public void changeTextColor(int color){
    textPaint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();
}

public void changeCircleColor(int color){
    circlePaint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

get the reference of this view and when you get color from color picker call **changeColor** method

or Here is working solution [Finger-Paint](https://github.com/nikt/Finger-Paint)

Comment: public void colorChanged(int color) {
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, color).commit();
mPaint.setColor(color);
} I have done already. Kindly see the image and my Question again @Vipin !

Comment: Ok I got it . Post your code I don't have any working example for that . might u may missing a bit only

Comment: Solution  Finger-Pain not found yaar.. @Vipin